# Asp controls not working on Chrome

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I m facing a weird problem here, none of my asp controls is working in Chrome, i'm unable to access event the text box don' t know why this arises??

Can some one help me regarding this?

Directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB"  Debug="true" EnableViewState="true" CompilationMode="Always"  AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Enquiry.aspx.vb" Inherits="Enquiry" %>
```

This is my textbox coding:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtContactAddress" CssClass="TextArea" ToolTip="Enter Contact Address" runat="server" Width="380px" Height="75px" TextMode="MultiLine" ValidationGroup="Enquiry"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am using HTML 5 tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I have included above doctypes..!!

The controls are working in IE 11 perfectly, i haven't tested it in anyother IE version, but it is not working in chrome, the control appears like an image in the chrome browser

I'm Using Visual-Studio-2013

**Web.config:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**

I have got the answer..!! :) Hurray, but it is weird..! I was having the controls inside a section tag whose css had position:relative and z-index:600; I removed the position:relative and it is woking fine..! Dont know why the Position:relative disabled the Asp.net controls??

Any solutions are welcome..!!

Comment: Have you checked Console?

Comment: console?? can you please elaborate it..!!

Comment: Press f12 when you are on chrome and you will see console tab.

Comment: if there is no html5 tags it is running fine..!!

Comment: Which tags did you remove?

Comment: im having two pages in asp website.. one i designed first without html5 tags in that i put these controls but it worked fine and other  i designed it with html5 tags..!! it is not working in this page..!!

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian: if you find the solution, instead of editing your question, please add an answer. This will help to see the question as answered.

Comment: @SteveB i have found i it but i need to know the reason how come postion:relative disable the button..!! :(